# can ScanCommand in aws-sdk lib-dynamodb fetch only n items as passed in input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am aware that ScanCommand in aws-sdk may not be costly wise if the load is huge, so is there away for it to only fetch, let say 100 first items in the table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of items in the result set with [Limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_RequestSyntax).

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js.
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
// Set the AWS Region.
AWS.config.update({ region: "REGION" });

// Create DynamoDB service object.
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

const params = {
  // Specify which items in the results are returned.
  FilterExpression: "Subtitle = :topic AND Season = :s AND Episode = :e",
  // Define the expression attribute value, which are substitutes for the values you want to compare.
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":topic": {S: "SubTitle2"},
    ":s": {N: 1},
    ":e": {N: 2},
  },
  Limit: 100, //Limit: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  // Set the projection expression, which are the attributes that you want.
  ProjectionExpression: "Season, Episode, Title, Subtitle",
  TableName: "EPISODES_TABLE",
};

ddb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    data.Items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      console.log(
          "printing",
          element.Title.S + " (" + element.Subtitle.S + ")"
      );
    });
  }
});
```

For more details, you can refer:
[Limiting the number of items in the result set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination)